# Displaying Date and Time on separate UILabel's in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am adding the date and time to my iOS app. I have successfully added the date but want to show the time on a different label.

My code looks like this but I'm getting an error 'Redefinition of dateFormatter'. What can I do to call the time on a separate label?

```
    NSLocale *en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    assert(en_US_POSIX != nil);

    // The Date

    //set the date label correctly
    //format the date to July 9 2013 - MMMM d yyyy
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
//    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:curDate];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d yyyy"];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    labelDate.text = theDate;

// The Time



    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    labelTime.text = resultString;
```

Comment: Your error means you have declared **dateFormatter** variable more than once, (you are declaring it three times) as you may know variable names should be unique, so change the name of your variable so they don't repeat.

Comment: Or just use one NSDateFormatter object and change the format as needed.

Comment: Its pretty clear from your question that you don't understand the basics of programming in any C family language, and you're trying to just splice together code you find online whiteout really understanding it. You should stop and read a book/tutorial series on programming basics before trying to copy/paste your way to application development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your just need to delete the line where you are reinitializing the NSDateFormatter.

Correct code is :

```
NSLocale *en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
assert(en_US_POSIX != nil);

// The Date

//set the date label correctly
//format the date to July 9 2013 - MMMM d yyyy
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
//    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:curDate];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d yyyy"];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateFromString];
labelDate.text = theDate;

// The Time

NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
labelTime.text = resultString;
```

Answer (score 0):

dude just change the NSDateFormatter name :) that's it, your problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSLocale *en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    assert(en_US_POSIX != nil);

    //format the date to July 9 2013 - MMMM d yyyy
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    // dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:curDate];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d yyyy"];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    labelDate.text = theDate;

    // The Time
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    labelTime.text = resultString;
```

Comment: ok, try to avoid creating more object and reuse them